# What does bitshift do to a range in Rust?

Tags: rust, range, bit-shift

I'm reading code that contains the following (slightly altered) Rust code:

```rust
let new_var : Vec<...> = (0..1 << some_number)
                         .into_par_iter()
                         .map(...)
                         .collect();
```

I recognize that it iterates over a range and constructs elements of a Vec for each number.
But why does it bitshift the `0..1` range? What is the resulting iterator that gets iterated over?

Comment: `<<` has higher precedence than `..`. Only the 1 is shifted.

Comment: @interjay what's the point of answering in the comments? | If you are able, can you explain how did precedence result in that? Feels unintuitive that `..`, with its direct "physical" contact, loses the "race"

Comment: I didn't have time for a full answer. I wouldn't call it counterintuitive given that the alternative (shifting a range) wouldn't make sense. The formatting (where spaces are and aren't placed) is what makes this confusing. But I would use parentheses to make the code clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left shift operator [`<<` has higher precedence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence) than range operator(`..`). So `1 << some_number` evaluates first.

You can also use the [HIR(High-Level Intermediate Representation) as an output mode in rust playground to see how rust compiler](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2e0a3c98e31086eec0585a0a1c8807a) parse/generate the `HIR` for the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let a = (0..1 << 2).into_par_iter();
}
```

*HIR*

```
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::rust_2021::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
fn main() {
    let a = #[lang = "Range"]{ start: 0,  end: 1 << 2,}.into_par_iter();
    //                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: feels counterintuitive... what was the reason for such choice?

Comment: @NooneAtAll3 Because most operators (all?) cannot be applied to ranges, so instead of having to wrap in parentheses, you can apply the operator directly to the end operand.